# Define AWS EventBridge catch-all rule using CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

In CDK rule definition , 'source' is an array of Strings:

```
 eventPattern: {
        source: []
      }
```

How do I define a catch-all rule?

Comment: The suggested solution is not type compatible with CDK. CDK requires 'source' to be String[], and "source": [{"prefix": "" }] throws a compilation-time error.

Comment: Check the other answers.